# Join separator in R fread shell command

Tags: r, unix, join, data.table, txt

I have two .txt files that I want to join using the R data.table *fread* function's shell command feature as a pre-processing step before importing into R. The two files are:

```
foods.txt:

ID|FOOD
100000853384|Cheese
100003735682|Potato
100006367485|Apple
100007267644|Beef

food_types.txt:

ID|TYPE
100000853384|Fat
100003735682|Carbohydrate
100006367485|Fruit
100007267644|Protein
```

I tried this code

```
library(data.table)
foods <- fread(cmd = paste("join -t '|' food_types.txt foods.txt"))
```

But it returns an error saying

```
''' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However, the join works properly if I change the delimiter to a comma and use

```
foods <- fread(cmd = paste("join -t ',' food_types.txt foods.txt"))
```

How can I get the join to work with the pipe delimiter? I am using R version 4.1.3 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: You are using the unix `join` command on a Windows machine? Are you using something like cygwin or WSL?

Comment: I am using the unix `join` command within an R command, using the `fread` function from the `data.table` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you switch the double and single quotes?

```
fread(cmd = paste('join -t "|" food_types.txt foods.txt'))
```

Output:

```
             ID         TYPE\r   FOOD
1: 100000853384          Fat\r Cheese
2: 100003735682 Carbohydrate\r Potato
3: 100006367485        Fruit\r  Apple
4: 100007267644        Protein   Beef
```